# Tabular Information on Custom Form - Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

Is there a way to have a form in Netsuite show fields as a table? I want it to be easy for people to enter related data together and perhaps show it as a table.

Or should I just create a related record to show this information as a table in a subtab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes! you can create a custom SubList and allow the users to enter data. Then you can access the sublist by its name to retrieve the records. Here is a simple example to collect list of locations.

```
var form = nlapiCreateForm('My Locations');
var sublist = form.addSubList("locations", "inlineeditor", "locations")
sublist.addField("address", "text", "Addresse");
sublist.addField("phone", "phone", "Phone");
sublist.addField("email", "email", "E-mail");
sublist.setUniqueField("email");
response.writePage(form);
```